# wrong number of arguments 1 for 0 in sent folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my custom inbox messaging system I am setting up the sent messages folder. I get a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`. The title of the page is ArgumentError in MessagesController#index. I can't seem to properly define the methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have tried a few things but can't seem to get it to work. I am sure it is a small fix as normal, but I'm new to rails so I don't know all the methods yet.

user.rb:

```
  def received_messages
      Message.received_by(self)
    end

 def unread_messages?
   unread_message_count > 0 ? true : false
 end

 def sent_messages
   Message.sent_by(self)
 end
```

message.rb:

```
     class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :subject, :body, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recipient_deleted
validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"

belongs_to :sender,
:class_name => 'User',
:foreign_key => 'sender_id'
belongs_to :recipient,
:class_name => 'User',
:foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

# marks a message as deleted by either the sender or the recipient, which ever the user that was passed is.
# When both sender and recipient marks it deleted, it is destroyed.
def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
     self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id
     self.recipient_deleted = true if self.recipient_id == user_id
     (self.sender_deleted && self.recipient_deleted) ? self.destroy : self.save!
 end
# Read message and if it is read by recipient then mark it is read
def readingmessage
  self.read_at ||= Time.now
  save
end

# Based on if a message has been read by it's recipient returns true or false.
def read?
    self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
end

def self.received_by(user)
   where(:recipient_id => user.id)
 end

 def self.not_recipient_deleted
   where("recipient_deleted = ?", false)
 end

 def self.sent_by(user)
   user.messages.sent
 end
```

end

messages_controller:

```
 def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
  end
```

inbox.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "View Sent Messages", user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox => :sent)%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your definition of Message.sent_by is incorrect, try:

```
 # message.rb
 def self.sent_by(user)
   Message.where(:sender_id => user.id)
 end
```

Comment: That gives undefined method `messages'

Comment: Can you include all the code from your user and message classes?